# How describe with typescript axios request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have thunk action with axios request but it's failed when instead of request I get error because below my reducer wait for data with IUser types but instead got error
messages from server

My code:

```
export const checkAuth = createAsyncThunk(
    `authService/checkAuth`,
    async (prevLocation:string) => {

        const response = await axios.get<IUser>('/api/auth/current')
        return {user:response.data, isAuth: true}
    }
)
```

Question:
How correctly handle axios request, errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do with async/await code is to always implement try/catch blocks, so situations like that won't happen, and the error will be properly handled.

```
async () => {
  let response; // properly typed
  try {
    response = await axios.get<IUser>('/api/auth/current')
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex) // handle exception
  }
}
```

You can now add proper logic to handle your error and return valid stuff :)

Comment: As I understand to describe erro type in catch block we need to use ant type? and what about axios interseptors, if we get error not from try catch block but from interseptors?